# Angular 5 Firebase the application logs out on refresh

Tags: typescript, firebase, angular5

I'm trying to build a web app using angular and firebase, which has a login form and a home page.

The problem is when I log in, it takes me to the home page as intended, but on clicking any link or even refresh the home page, it logs me out!

My login.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { User } from '../_helpers/user';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  user: User;
  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router) {
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.user = new User("","");
    if( this.authService.isLoggedIn() )
      this.router.navigate(['home']);
  }
  onSubmit() {
    this.authService.login(this.user.email, this.user.password);
    this.user.email = this.user.password = '';
    this.router.navigate(['home']);
  }
}
```

my home.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Database } from '../_helpers/database';
import { AuthGuard } from '../_helpers/authGuard';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  database : Database;
  carsObservable: Observable<any[]>;
  constructor(
    private db: AngularFireDatabase,
    private authService: AuthService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {    
    if( !this.authService.isLoggedIn() ){
      this.router.navigate(['login']);
      return;
    }
    this.database = new Database(this.db, this.route, this.router);
    this.carsObservable = this.database.getCars();
  }
}
```

and the auth.service.ts

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  user: Observable<firebase.User>;
  static result = false;
  constructor(private firebaseAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
    this.user = firebaseAuth.authState;
  }

  login(email: string, password: string) {
    this.firebaseAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(value => {
        console.log('signedIn');
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('NotYet: ',err.message);
      });
  }

  isLoggedIn() : boolean{
    this.firebaseAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      if(user){
        AuthService.result = true;
      }else{
        AuthService.result = false;
      }
    });
    return AuthService.result;
  }

  /*logout() : void{
    this.firebaseAuth.auth.signOut();
  }*/
}
```